# file descriptor written in xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xsd, metadata, file-format

I am looking to parse log files (text files usually delimited by certain characters), and I want to make the job easier by making a parser that can take in an xml file which describes the format of the log file coming in. This way I can feed my parser any type of log file and with my xml description my parser and extract the useful information. I am not sure how to generically describe the log file format in xml. Also I am unsure about how to then match lines in my log file with the descriptions given. I would greatly appreciate any help and guidance on this. Thank you very much to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<logfile location="/usr/local/logs/logfile.log">
    <delimiter>#</delimiter>
    <format>
        <field index="1" length="10">
            <target>Date</target>
        </field>
        <field index="2">
            <target>Message</target>
        </field>
        <field index="3" length="20">
            <target>Component</target>
        </field>
        <field index="5" length="20">
            <target>Details</target>
        </field>
    </format>
</logfile>
```

Your code will read this XML and parse each line in the log file dynamically according to the rules defined here. The program will then store the values in appropriate 'target' fields.

log file:

```
2012/12/12 10.10.10#Critical application state#Error in component XYZ#Useless information#Useful information
```

Output:

```
Date: 2012/12/12
Message: Critical application state
Component: Error in component XYZ
Details: Useful information
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I am still a little unsure about how to parse the xml file once I have a proper description. Could I by any chance see how you parsed this example? I am attempting to implement this parser in java using the provided API for xml. Thank you again for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit undecided concerning the length attribute in the XML above. It would be ok if it states the amount of text of the corresponding field to be written (then the name could be more precise). If it is used as maximum string size it is difficult to maintain (first a parse of log file is needed to determine the correct value) and may lead to exceptions if not set up properly.

Comment: @guidot - It's the number of characters to read from a field.

Comment: @sreehari - Thank you. I'm still unsure about how to parse the xml file once I have a proper description, it would be great if I could see how you did that. To get a description I provide a format inside each tag. Together the tag contents describes the format of a line. Yet it wont recognize the delimiters and im not sure why.  Thank you, I really do appreciate it.                                                             <field id="TimeStamp">(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:)(\d+)</field>
<delimiter id ="delim">(\s+)|(\s+)</delimiter>